# remove uitabbar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to iPhone development, my problem is that I have a `UITabbar` in my app. It will display after sign in. when I want to log out from my app, want to go back to the sign in view controller, so the tab bar should be removed from the sign in view controller shown. So how do I do that?

I tried hiding tab bars, but that didn't work.

Comment: "question"? u meant tht? --" quit ion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In appdelegate make your loginView as rootView controller, after login make your tabBar as rootView and at the time of logout remove tabBar from rootView and make loginView to as rootView.

or

in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController *yourTabBar;
```

Make function to add tabBar instance `-(void)addTabBar` in app delegate this method add your all view to tabBar, Dont add this as subView to window,just make it.
And add your LoginView as rootViewController.

after login add tabBar as subView

```
TUTAppDelegate *appdelegte =(TUTAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte yourTabBar]view]];
```

and at logout button

```
TUTAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TUTAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[[appDelegate yourTabBar] view]removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: login to the app is in login view controller.so uitabbar was made in there ,when a login button pressed go to tabbar view with 5 tab bar items.so this code can't use in there,have any different idea?

Comment: Put your tabBar in appDelegate,...

Comment: i put login button action  under and how it doing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having a modalViewController in front of the TabBar??

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[About View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

Comment: so, to sigin you present a modalview controller, when logedin dismiss it..

Answer (score 0):

this is my login button action how to put thid in appdelegate and if it place appdelegate how it access in login button

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init ];

                    UINavigationController *statusNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
                    StatusViewController *statusViewController = [[StatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
                    statusViewController.title = @"Status";

                      statusViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"status.PNG"];
                    statusViewController.searchText=@"";
                    [statusNavigationController pushViewController:statusViewController animated:YES];


                    UINavigationController *messageNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
                    MessageViewController *messageViewController = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle:nil];
                    messageViewController.title = @"Messages";
                    messageViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"message.PNG"];

                    messageViewController.searchText=@"";
                    [messageNavigationController pushViewController:messageViewController animated:YES]

                    [tabBarController addChildViewController:statusNavigationController];
                    [tabBarController addChildViewController:messageNavigationController
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Comment: make property of tabBarController

Answer (score 0):

> Set the the sig in page and next page in different View or Xib.
>
> The UITabbar given to the 2nd Xib.
>
> When logOut point to firs View.