# Half of Tabbar not visible :((

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I am making an `iphone` application using iPhone sdk 4,

My application starts with a Normal View!

And when user presses a button, it goes to next view, This View must have a `Tabbar`,

> first view ==button==> Second View (with tabbar)

this is my `SecondviewController.m`

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize lab,tabbar;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:tabbar.view]; 

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [lab release];
    [tabbar release];
}

@end
```

It Works , but lower half of my dear tabbar is not visible.

Comment: can you set Your NIB properly ..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460013/remove-uitabbar-controller/12460244#12460244

Comment: what was the solution of yourProblem?

Comment: 2 solutions found -                               1- using setFrame for tabbarViewcontroller.    2- removing status bar of view in IFB

Answer (score 1):

That is because of your navigation bar or the status bar which is been implemented due to which the tabbar is going below the original height of the screen i.e. 480 px. In your nib file click the view and in the simulated metrics try and change the top bar to none and see. Maybe this would help !!.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to add your tab bar to main window it will appear like

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview: tabbar.view];
```